# Unable to send data through AJAX to PHP file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a table that has anchor links for all the rows in one of the columns.

The relevant code is

```
<tbody>
  <?php foreach ($rowarr as $k => $v) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $k ?></td>
      <td>
        <div class="divBox">                          
          <a id="vendorlink" data-toggle="modal" data-vendor="<?= $v ?>" href="#myModal"><?php echo $v; ?></a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

I'm trying to send the name of the vendor from the link clicked in the table to a modal using AJAX and trying to print the name in the modal just for testing, but even that is not happening.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  $("#vendorlink").click(function(){
    var vendor = $(this).data('vendor');
    $('#myModal').on('shown', function(){                
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "ip.php",
          data:     "id=" + vendor,
          success: function(html){
            $("#modal-body").html(html);
            $('.countstable1').dataTable( {
              "sDom": "T<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
              "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
              "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
              },
              "aaSorting":[[0, "desc"]],
              "iDisplayLength": 10,
              "oTableTools": {
                    "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                    "aButtons": ["csv", "pdf"]
                  }
            });
          }
      });              
    });
  });
</script>
```

And the ip.php file only has this for the moment

```
<?php

$vendor = $_GET['id'];

echo $vendor;
?>
```

But in the modal I only see the default bootstrap markup code, nothing is echo'ed in there

This is the default bootstrap markup code - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

What could be wrong ? why is vendor not passing to the PHP file ?

Comment: Ditch the question mark in the data field.

Comment: @SamDufel - That doesn't seem to do anything. Still the same results.

Comment: Can you look at the ajax request in firebug / chrome net panel / etc?  It should look like `GET http://my-server.com/ip.php?id=xxx`

Comment: @SamDufel - I'm not sure if I'm looking the right way, but I don't see that php script being loaded in the network tab in CDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same id set for all the links in your html-file, that will not work as you want, you be better of adding an event to all of your links.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that ? Should I add on onclick event to a tag that runs that click function I have right now in the JS ?

Comment: It don't know about that, im not that used to JS but, id's are for unique items, and since you have a loop that will print out several links with the same id your script will probably not function correctly. My bet is that your better of testing your script incrementally. First of all find out if your script shows the modal (I have no idea what that is), then try sending the AJAX call.

Comment: And to answer your question, which I didn't (sorry about that) in JQuery for example has this syntax (I think): $(".classname").click(function(){ });

Answer (score 0):

The `data` property should be defined this way:

```
data: {id: vendor},
```

**Edit.** Oh and replace:

```
<a id="vendorlink" data-toggle="modal" data-vendor="<?= $v ?>" href="#myModal"><?php echo $v; ?></a>
```

with:

```
<a id="vendorlink_<?=$v?>" class="vendorlink" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"><?=$v?></a>
```

and `$("#vendorlink")` with `$(".vendorlink")` (so you'll affect *all of the entries*), and `$(this).data('vendor');` with `$(this).attr('id').replace('vendorlink_', '');`.

Comment: You should add a `console.log(html);` (or `alert(html);`) right after the `success` property to check whether something is actually sent back or not.

Comment: ok I added that as the first line in the success: function(html){} function, and it turns out to be undefined in the console. But I had to change the data definition to the one in the OP.

Comment: What does OP mean? So, if you put `data: {id: vendor}`, maybe should you verify that vendor is not empty?

Comment: Original Post. I did try `data: {id: vendor}`. It ended up empty. Are you sure that's the right method for GET ? 

Also am I getting the vendor right with this code `var vendor = $(this).data('vendor');   ` or does that need to be changed to something else ?

Comment: If you want to check whether `vendor` is correctly set, do a `console.log`. I think the code's okay. For the URL, it should work this way but if you wanna be sure, do `url: "ip.php?id=" + vendor` and no `data` property.

Comment: `console.log(vendor)` returns undefined. I'm guessing it's not the right way of getting that property's value.

Comment: Hmm, I understand your answer now and thought it would work for sure but it didn't. `console.log(vendor);` after the replace function doesn't even show anything now. Changed the data property to what you suggested too.

Comment: I don't understand. Are `$v` variables numbers? If they're not and if they contain spaces, this might explain.

Comment: That's it then. They are names with spaces and other special characters.

Comment: Well then it's `<a class="vendorlink" data-toggle="modal" data-vendor="<?=$v?>" href="#myModal"><?=$v;?></a>` and you get back to `$(this).data('vendor');`.